# Mention time in a log file using perl

Tags: perl

I want to generate a log file with time using perl script. I am able to generate a log file with all the logs i want to print.But the problem is happening as I cannot find when the log is generated and how long a process takes to execute.

My logfile prints below lines:

Error in add for ou=People,dc=egi,dc=example,dc=com: error code 68.Error in add for uid=Tanushree8,ou=,dc=example,dc=com: error code 34.Error in add for id=Tanushree44,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com: error code 68.

I want to print the time of error generation as well with the log. Please advise.

Comment: I answered without properly reading your question. Without providing more code/information it will be hard for anyone to tell you where your error occurs. You could wrap your code in a Try::Tiny block and catch+reformat the error msg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you just want to prepend the datetime to your existing code:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
my $msg = 'Hello World!';
sprintf(
   "%s %s",
   strftime("%F %H:%M:%S", localtime),
   $msg
);
print "$msg\n"
```

OR ... you could use one of the many logging related modules on CPAN.

I am currently using Log::Any for a project.

a) create a package initializing your logger

```
package MyApp::InitLogger;
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw/ say /;
use Log::Any::Adapter;
use Log::Dispatch;
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
my $log_file = '/var/log/myapp.log';

my $log = Log::Dispatch->new(
    outputs   => [
            [
            'Screen',
            name      => 'screen',
            min_level => 'debug',
            newline   => 1
            ],
            [
            'File',
            filename  => $log_file,
            min_level => 'debug',
            newline   => 1,
            mode      => 'append'
            ]
    ],
    callbacks => [
        sub {
            my %msg = @_;
            return sprintf(
                "%s %d %s",
                strftime("%F %H:%M:%S", localtime),
                $$,
                $msg{message}
            );
        }
    ]
);

Log::Any::Adapter->set( 'Dispatch', dispatcher => $log );

1;
```

b) wherever you want to log something

```
use MyApp::InitLogger;
use Log::Any qw/$log/;

$log->debug('hello world');
```